# getting Ill form expression in Scheme

Tags: scheme

I am using cond to remove the occurrence of the element in l in my tree (t).This is my attempt,logically it works.But why do I get Ill form expression? I have tried so many things but still got the same error.Thanks!

```
(define check (lambda (l t)
 (cond ((null? t) ‘())
   ((equal? (car l) (car (tree-labels t))) (check l (cdr(tree-labels t))))
   ((and (not(null? l))(equal? (cadr l) (car (tree-labels t))) (check l (cdr(tree-labels t))))
   (else (cons (car (tree-labels t)) (check l (cdr(tree-labels t)))) )))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a typo, you probably copied the code from a web page or ebook with the wrong font. Change this:

```
‘()
```

To this:

```
'()
```

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH @Óscar López .The code  is totally mine.It was my bad to type it first on a plain file and paste it on the command line.No wonder I got that error,the font is different.